# How to specify a piecewise bound for a variable in Gurobi?

Tags: gurobi

I have integer variables in my model, which cannot be = 1 or = 2, but can be = 0 or any integer > 2.

I thought this can be specified by:

```
Bounds

  X1 >= 3
  X2 >= 3
...
```

However, I realised this does not allow that the variable = 0, which I need it to be. Is there a way like:

```
X1 >= 3 OR X1 = 0
```

or

```
X1 cannot = 1 OR 2
```

I am using the .lp format with the gurobi_cl command line.

Answer (score 1):

In Gurobi you can create so-called [semi-continuous or semi-integer variables](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/variables.html). Such variables can be 0 or take any value between the specified bounds.

In Python, you would create them like this ([reference](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_addvar.html)):

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

model = gp.Model()
X1 = model.addVar(lb=2.0, vtype=GRB.SEMIINT, name="X1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to mattmilten's answer: Via the [big-m-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) you could do it "by hands", i.e. we are adding two additional constraints:

```
X1 <= 0 + M-M*b
X1 >= 3 - M*b
```

where b is binary variable and M a sufficiently large number > 0. Choosing M = 1000, we get:

```
Maximize
  ...
Subject To
  ...
  X1 + 1000 w <= 1000
  X1 + 1000 w >= 3
Generals
  X1
Binary
  b
End
```